# How to read .DS_Store files

Tags: objective-c, macos

Is there a way to read `.DS_Store` files using Objective-C under OSX, or an application for this purpose?

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just want to see what is written inside this file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any such publicly available API to read .DS_Store files.

You could look at [these notes](https://wiki.mozilla.org/DS_Store_File_Format), which describe the format, to work out how to read it yourself. However, I as it's an Apple proprietary format, I wouldn't be surprised if they've changed it since those notes were last updated in 2012.